# Criterion for an analytic variety to be a manifold

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Suppose V is some analytic variety of $P^n$ given by some equation. Is there a criterion for determining when it is a manifold of a particular dimension ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. First of all, every analytic subvariety of complex-projective space is actually algebraic (Chow's theorem). To determine whether the complex points of a variety form a manifold, it is enough to show that the variety is smooth. Determining the dimension of a connected component may then be done by checking the dimension of a local ring of a closed point of your variety (there are certainly other ways to check - there are several equivalent definitions of dimension).

Comment: Is there ways to determine whether a variety is smooth given it's determining equations ?

Comment: Yes! The Jacobian criteria. If your variety is given by the vanishing locus of $\{f_1,\cdots,f_m\}$ in variables $x_1,\cdots,x_n$, construct the Jacobian matrix where the $ij^{th}$ entry is $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}$. If this matrix is full rank everywhere on your variety, then your variety is smooth.

Comment: That is awesome. Thanks so much!